# .htaccess rule for setting directory rewrite if extension match

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

At the moment I have

```
RewriteRule ^olddir/(.*).xls newdir/one/$1.xls
RewriteRule ^olddir/(.*).jpg newdir/one/$1.jpg
```

At the moment all the file extensions I want to rewrite I put on a separate line.

I'm sure there is a shorter way to do `(.xls|.jpg)`? this but I lack htaccess skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe

```
RewriteRule ^olddir/(.+)\.(jpg|xls)$ newdir/one/$1.$2
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^olddir/(.+\.(jpg|xls))$ newdir/one/$1
```

not sure about the second one as I haven't tried it, but should work... and changed * to + because there probably should be at least one char there and added a \ to the . or else it will match any char

Also, if you need help with the regex that mod_rewrite uses, check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html